# How to change price format in Magento 1

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am getting stuck over 1 days to find how to change price format in Magento.
My current store displaying the price format like (US$1.114,50) but I need the correct format is (US$1,114.50).

So, everyone here know how to change this format?

Thank you so much for your kindly help.

Comment: How US$1.114,50 is equal to US$1,114.50?

Comment: Yes the price is equal, just want to change the group(,) and dicimal(.) in my country they are using format US$0.00 but in Magento defual format is US$0,00 , so, I want to change it. Do you have idea, sir?

Comment: You can not add 1.114,50 price for any products. due to the comma sign. and without comma it become 1.11450 so when we add product or change price from admin it save 1.11
Same price (1.11) will show on frontend.

Comment: in Admin I added product price by (1.50) but at the frontend display (1,50).

Comment: It should be 1.50 I think you did some formatting customization for frontend like str_replace. Please check product detail view.phtml and check price block.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting price in Magento

There are a couple of methods to format price in Magento. The easiest and most used is:

```
Mage::helper("core")->currency($price, $format, $includeContainer)
```

Example:

```
echo Mage::helper("core")->currency(115, true, false)
//if your currency is Euro then output will be: €115.00
```

Sometimes you don’t need currency symbols in your prices, then you will need something like:

```
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->setData("currency_code", Mage::app()->getStore(null)->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode())->format(
    $product->getFinalPrice(), 
    array('display' =>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), false);
```

The value for the display can be Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL (it will remove the symbol and show only the price) Zend_Currency::USE_SYMBOL (shows the currency symbol before the price), Zend_Currency::USE_SHORTNAME (shows the abbreviation of the currency before the price) or Zend_Currency::USE_NAME (shows the full name of the currency before the price). Example outputs:

```
Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL:         115.00
Zend_Currency::USE_SYMBOL:       €115.00
Zend_Currency::USE_SHORTNAME:  EUR115.00
Zend_Currency::USE_NAME:      EURO115.00
```